# Can't build Java project on OSX yosemite

Tags: java, macos, gradle

I am blocked by the following error

```
com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.put(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Here is the full trace

```
➜  project git:(master) ✗ gradle jar --stacktrace 
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.put(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.put(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getStandardFileManager(JavacTool.java:89)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getStandardFileManager(JavacTool.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.createCompileTask(JdkJavaCompiler.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 44 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.31 secs
```

I am running Java 8 on OSX 10.10.4. I have my `JAVA_HOME` set and I have installed the oracle JDK. I am currently using grade to build my project.

```
➜ project git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-02-16 05:09:33 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     586be72bf6e3df1ee7676d1f2a3afd9157341274

Groovy:       2.3.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64
```

I have also made sure that I have JAVA_HOME set

```
➜  project git:(master) ✗ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have also ensured that the correct version of Java is getting selected by passing gradle the exact java path however the result is the same.

```
➜  project git:(master) ✗ gradle clean build -Dorg.gradle.java.home='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home'
:clean
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.put(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.883 secs
```

Any suggestions as to what is causing this error?

**UPDATE**

I can confirm this issue is also happening with Maven. I have also tried using JDK 1.7 from within intellij and the same issue remains.

Comment: Could you post the full log when you attempt to build the project?

Comment: Hey David thanks for the quick reply. Just updated the post then.

Comment: After searching for a little while, I've come across some issues with OSX 10.10 and Java 8. The best example of this: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/issues/1422 (from last year)

Some information on target versions in gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-build-java-1-8-even-with-proper-java-version-in-use/2461/8

Comment: Thanks for these. I have seen them however I have found articles such as http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/21/get-java-os-x-yosemite/ that suggest that there is no issue doing this. The second article seems to be a separate issue as the op there does not seem to have their java configured correctly. Thanks again for these though but I'm not sure either really addresses the issue.

Comment: @Stewart Did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same problem and have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @phinetune. Not yet. Can you vote up if your looking for a solution as well. Might help this question get noticed a bit more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try clearing out your /Library/Java/Extensions folder.

I had the same error with a very similar setup and moving aside all the files in that folder fixed it for me.

One of the .jar files I had in that folder seems to be dodgy or was interfering with the JDK in some weird way (I didn't take the time to find out which one)

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff   228K 14 Aug  2012 KeyStoreBE.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff    62K 14 Aug  2012 activation.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff   101K 14 Aug  2012 jaxb-api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff   847K 14 Aug  2012 jaxb-impl.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff    45K 14 Aug  2012 jsr173_1.0_api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff   383K 14 Aug  2012 log4j-1.2.15.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff   425K 14 Aug  2012 mail.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 benloft  staff   6.7M 14 Aug  2012 tools.jar
```

I suspect they were installed as part of the dodgy AUSKEY I had to use a while back

Comment: AUSKey has been one of worst things ever created, caused me nothing but problems.. and this has been my problem

Comment: Bravo dude. I painstakingly went through and deleted each jar file, quit the emulator, quit Android Studio, restart Android Studio, clean project, build app and narrowed down the problem to the `tools.jar` file. Yes, I had used AUSKey in the past too :P Not sure what tools.jar does but hopefully not something important. For anyone reading this, after deleting the `tools.jar` file, make sure you quit the emulator, quit Android Studio, reopen Android Studio, do a `Build > Clean Project` then try building your app onto your phone/emulator again.

Comment: tools.jar solved it for me too.  On my Ubuntu install it's /usr/java/packages/lib/ext/

Answer (score 0):

Seconded - removing everything from `/Library/Java/Extensions` fixed an identical problem with Android Studio on my Mac. I also suspect `AUSKEY` was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here didn't work for me on Mac OS X El Capitan

Firstly, I cleared out the /Library/Java/Extensions file, then

I ran this command in the Android Studio Terminal to rebuild Gradle

`./gradlew clean assemble`

After the install, everything ran smoothly.