# Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am developing an Android App in Android Studio. Not quite sure what went wrong. I was successfully building a few days ago. Any help would be great.

Here is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.tubbs.citychurchob"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Go to Run -> Edit Configuration -> Gradle -> + Gradle -> Tasks:build, Script parameters: --info --debug -> Apply -> Run with new configurations -> Now you will be able to the details. Paste that logs in here.

Comment: Is this under default?

Comment: Go to File > Project Structure. Select builds tools version from unrecognised value.

Comment: I solved this error due a bad import in project ... in Terminal type /gradlew assemble{Your Buile Type} --scan ... and it will output error in console.

Comment: I accidentally typed `«` somewhere in my codebase and it caused this issue.

Comment: This is very late but in hope it will help someone in the future. The way I solved this issue was removing duplicate react packages in app/build.gradle It seems like every time I run react-native link, packages are copied again.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try to upgrade your `buildToolsVersion` to "23.0.1", like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

If you didn't install the buildTools for this version, please download it with SDKManager as hint.

Comment: Just tried and it's didn't work, I mean the build still failed.

Comment: Please try to clean and rebuild,I think maybe some dependency jars has outdated.

Comment: Make sure your jdk version>=7.

Comment: I imported an old project that is an exact copy and it works now. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: i just changed `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: I tryed 23.0.1, 23.0.2, everything in project structure (intellij) pointing to 1.7, ./gradlew --version and javac both points to 1.7, JAVA_HOME set to point to 1.7 and still no luck - I always somehow manage to make it work but I always forget how. This is magic :(

Comment: Where should I make these changes? I pulled a react native app and facing this error while making a build.

Comment: Worked. As of AndroidStudio 3.0.1 following line is not required.  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Comment: I which file I have to change it ?

Comment: Its smart answer is that there is some syntax error in your Code may be in Java file or xml. FIx them error will gone.  work 100 percent for me every time

Comment: This answer did not solve the problem, I had to add the sdk location to my environment variable to solve the problem.

Comment: It is not at all depend on version.@live-love answer is the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: Not really a solution or explanation

Comment: hi @starkshang which file do you apply these changes onto?

Comment: hi all, May be worked for someone but not working for me:(

Comment: I updated compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 29 to 30 and it worked! thanks

Comment: upgrading  my gradle to `gradle:7.0.0` and my gradle wrapper to `/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip` worked for me.

Answer (score 132):

In Android Studio 3.1, you can see the errors details in the Build window.

Open up Build tab. They are somewhat hidden, you have to expand the Java compiler node. You will see the errors there.

[image]

But there is a better way to see the errors. You can click on the Toggle View button to get a better view of the error. That way you don't have to expand each node.

[image]

Comment: I had issue with Google Paging library that was not java 8 compatible, I had to update all my dependencies and error was gone.

Comment: had an error in imports and it didnt show up until i try this way :)

Comment: For me this directed me to see my errors, hadn't included some dependenciey, so error in clsses.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.3.1 and I would say this does not definitely answer the question but it is very useful for debugging it. Thanks man, this solution saved my hours finding the bug.

Comment: You saved my life when i use the room framework for my database all error of key are hidden in the java compiler but are displayed in toogle view

Comment: No longer valid in AS 4+ These options no longer exist.

Comment: Same issue for me, upgrade  my gradle to gradle:7.0.0' and my gradle wrapper to /gradle-7.0.2-all.zip worked for me.

Answer (score 56):

This kind of problem really make us anxious because of that no more useful information will be provided.

I don't know we are really the same,but I can provide two ways to help us try to solve the problem.

1.Firstly you can try to clean or restart your Android Studio & your computer.In China,we have a saying between developers.

***Little problems,just restart.Big problems,should reinstall.***

The above saying will help you to solve this kind of problem many times.

2.Secondly we need to use some gradle command to help you to find more useful details.

I have met the similar situation as below:

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:137)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 29 more
```

You know that the above log is not useful for us to solve this kind of problem.We need to do some gradle command to find more useful information.

Note:I use macOS(10.13) and Android Studio(3.1)

Go to your Android project directory to execute the gradle command below:

> `./gradlew assembleDebug --info`

Note:If you have permission problems while executing the above command,you can use this to deal with it:

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

And then I got this(Some unimportant parts are omitted):

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' into context took 0.0 secs.
file or directory '/Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/app/src/debug/java', not found
Up-to-date check for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' took 0.009 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compiling with source level 1.7 and target level 1.7.
Creating new cache for classAnalysis, path /Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/.gradle/4.4.1/javaCompile/classAnalysis.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@156d7504
Creating new cache for jarAnalysis, path /Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/.gradle/4.4.1/javaCompile/jarAnalysis.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@156d7504
Creating new cache for taskJars, path /Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/.gradle/4.4.1/javaCompile/taskJars.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@156d7504
Creating new cache for taskHistory, path /Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/.gradle/4.4.1/javaCompile/taskHistory.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@156d7504
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
file or directory '/Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/app/src/debug/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/app/src/main/java/com/chipsguide/app/colorbluetoothlamp/v2/karmalighting/frags/banner/VideoActivity.java:10: error: package com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.model does not exist
import com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.model.Video;
                                               ^
/Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/app/src/main/java/com/chipsguide/app/colorbluetoothlamp/v2/karmalighting/frags/banner/VideoActivity.java:11: error: package com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.model does not exist
import com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.model.VideoUrl;
                                               ^
/Users/ifeegoo/workspace/android/android-bluetooth-color-lamp-karma-lighting/app/src/main/java/com/chipsguide/app/colorbluetoothlamp/v2/karmalighting/frags/banner/VideoActivity.java:12: error: package com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.view does not exist
import com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.view.MediaController;
                                              ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
35 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.84 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
15 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 14 up-to-date
```

I have got the most important details information,because of one module imported not properly which makes the class not found.So, I got it and solve the problem.

Some other gradle command:

```
*clean project
./gradlew clean  

*build project
./gradlew build

*build for debug package
./gradlew assembleDebug or ./gradlew aD

*build for release package
./gradlew assembleRelease or ./gradlew aR

*build for release package and install
./gradlew installRelease or ./gradlew iR Release

*build for debug package and install
./gradlew installDebug or ./gradlew iD Debug

*uninstall release package
./gradlew uninstallRelease or ./gradlew uR

*uninstall debug package
./gradlew uninstallDebug or ./gradlew uD 

*all the above command + "--info" or "--debug" or "--scan" or "--stacktrace" can get more detail information.
```

**If you cannot get enough information by --info,please use --debug/--scan/--stacktrace instead.**

***Remember that the more details will help you to solve the problem the more.***

> Note:Gradle commands are really powerful,if you want to do more complicated operation,especially about how to deal with debug/release or multi-channels or modules,go to Android Studio to check the Gradle Window,then you will know how to do it!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a better understanding of what was going on

Comment: @KutiGbolahan These gradle commands help us to get more details of the building process.

Comment: I found the problem just by this command `./gradlew assembleDebug --info`. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

This is because your $JAVA_HOME is not set. If you are using a Mac:

`export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home"`
in .bash_profile

Comment: Worked for me. Set it to my Jenkins setting configuration.

Comment: Be careful and set proper jdk version for your system

Comment: Its smart answer is that there is some syntax error in your Code may be in Java file or xml. FIx them error will gone.  work 100 percent for me every time

Comment: Type export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- and then click tab to find your correct version, then keep on typing /Contents/Home

Comment: Fyi to find where it should point to type "/usr/libexec/java_home" in the console it will return you the correct path

Comment: Same issue here. My JAVA_HOME was pointing to an OpenJDK version 11. After setting it to a 1.8 the build worked.

Comment: After set new export of JAVA_HOME don't foget to reload: `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 30):

I've tried both of the provided answers. But none of them worked.

*I think the solution is the following:*

In your project, *go to* `Gradle Scripts` >> `build.gradle (Module:app)` then remove the lines below (if they present)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
```

After removing it `clean` the project, then `run` it again.

No need to set `JAVA_HOME`, nor change the version.

Comment: Solution: File -> Sync project with gradle. its working for me.

Comment: this was my problem. 
Removing the entire compileOptions bracket containing JavaVersions solved it for me.

Comment: It worked for me by adding below my app/build.gradle to make my Android project compilation be compatible with Java 8 with `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` and `targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`

Answer (score 24):

Set JDK location in project settings
[image]

Comment: I had to uncheck 'use built in JRE' to do this, but once I did, everything worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

If all the above didn't work for you try removing cache from `.gradle` global folder

### Try the following

`rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches`

`react-native run-android`

### If didn't work, the below worked perfectly for me

`rm -rf ~/.gradle`

`react-native run-android`

Comment: but this example related to react android

Comment: Yes the question is about react native android error as well

Comment: deleting the whole .gradle folder worked in my case. thanks!

Answer (score 12):

### Update (06/05/2017)

I wanted to use **Realm** for Android and that required **Retrolambda**. Problem is Retrolambda conflicts with Jack.

So I removed my Jack options config from my gradle shown in original answer below and made the following changes:

```
// ---------------------------------------------
// Project build.gradle file
// ---------------------------------------------
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and

```
// ---------------------------------------------
// Module build.gradle file
// ---------------------------------------------
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    ...
```

### Tools.jar

If you made those changes above and you still get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.put(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Try removing the following file:

```
/Library/Java/Extensions/tools.jar
```

Then:

1. Quit emulator
2. Quit Android Studio
3. Reopen Android Studio
4. Build > Clean Project
5. Run/debug your app onto your device/emulator again

All the changes fixed it for me.

Note:

I am not sure what tools.jar does or whether it's important. Like other uses in this Stackoverflow question:

[Can't build Java project on OSX yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676045/cant-build-java-project-on-osx-yosemite)

We were unfortunate enough to have to use AUSKey (some ancient dinosaur Java authentication key system used by Australian Government to authenticate our computer before we can log into Australian business portal website).

My speculation is `tools.jar` might have been a JAR file for/by AUSKey.

If you're worried, instead of deleting this file, you can make a backup of the whole folder and save it somewhere just in case you can't login to Australian Business Portal again.

Hope that helps :D

### Original Answer

I came across this problem today (27/06/2016).

I downloaded Android Studio 2.2 and updated JDK to 1.8.

In addition to the above answers of pointing to the correct JDK path, I had to additionally specify the JDK version in my `build.gradle(Module: app)` file:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.appname"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please also notice if you came across an error about `Java 8 language features requires Jack enabled`, you need to add the following to your gradle file (as shown above):

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

After doing that, I finally got my new project app running on my phone.

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue after upgrading the Android studio to version 2.2.2, I solved it by using embedded JDK as recommended :
[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio open:
`File > Project Structure` and check if JDK location points to your JDK 1.8 directory.

Note: you can use `compileSdkVersion 24`.
It works trust me. For this to work first download latest JDK from Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue **solved**.

I was trying to compile this project  "Waveform Android" - https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android

and got I this error.

I am using Android studio on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I have JAVA 8 Installed.

in my gradle build script file there was some statements as below.

```
retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME")
    oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME")
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

I changed the **"JAVA8_HOME" to "JAVA_HOME"** because in my environment variables the java home directory is set as JAVA_HOME not as JAVA8_HOME and then It built succesfully.

after changing the build script.

```
retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
    oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME")
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Or the other way you can create a new environment variable named **JAVA8_HOME** pointing to the right JDK location, but I have not tried that though because I dont want environment variables for each JDK version.

Comment: Retrolambda was my issue. I was hardcoding an old Java Home version but then upgraded and forgot to update. Switching to this automated way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on Mac OS Sierra on my way to running a **React Native Android App** for the first time:

`Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`

`> Could not find tools.jar`

I changed my JAVA HOME environment variable for Java Development Kit (JDK) from:

`export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'`

to :

`export JAVA_HOME='/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home'`

I figured out where the correct version was after creating a project in Android Studio and looking for the JDK location in the project settings.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your app's build.gradle.
I had the same problem, finally I found the problem was in my build.gradle file dependencies{}, it add extra .jar file which actually didn't exist in my project as dependency. So I delete this dependency, and the problem has gone.

Comment: This is the answer. I had replaced a library in libs folder. But when I looked into the build.gradle file, the old library was remaining there as a dependancy. I had to manually delete the entry from build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just in naming folder, if your folder to save your project contains special characters then remove them. If the error persists try to save the folder with no space.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and already tried all of solutions but to no avail.

It turned out that using **Java 9 was the problem**. Installing a lower version Java (**jdk 1.8.0_162**) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing @yuchaozh [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907545/4975783) that helped me solve it.
(I don't have rep to comment)

Run this to know which java version you have

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

You'll get an output like:

```
jdk1.8.0_111.jdk
```

Replace with your Java version and run this command to export the correct path.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<YOUR_JAVA_VERSION>/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your gradle files might be corrupted. Try running

`./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`

in the terminal inside android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when I tried to use retrolambda inside my unit tests. I didn't find a solution how to make retrolambda work with unit tests. So, I use old fashioned anonymous classes instead of lambdas with my unit tests, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use these settings and it will work fine.

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pm.motivator"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: -_- compile and build version is different is the not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

in build file change **compile files('AF-Android-SDK.jar')** to **compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar')** it will work

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I was working with a team of developers using a Mac and everybody else on the team was running Windows. However we were using the Anroid Studio 2.2-beta with jdk 1.8. If you are on a mac and come across this issue, here is how to solve it. DONT USE Android Studio 2.2-beta. I spent hours trying to debug this error in 2.2-beta. ***I solved it by simply changing to Android Studio 2.1.3***. Our app ran instantly after changing the Android Studio version. Also on Android Studio's website before you download it warns mac users about running jdk 1.8 on 2.2 beta. Guess I should have read the fine print haha

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error.
JAVA_HOME pointing to the correct version of JDK.
All support libraries and build tools updated.
Was still facing the same issue.

I am using Android annotations in my project.
I added a new View..and there was already an existing view with the same name in the Java file.
When I run the project, instead of indicating the view already exists, I was receiving the above error.

Check your java files errors if other solutions does not work.

Comment: So, how this answers the question? Please, clarify your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you are using Android+Lambdas. Sometimes I can use Lambdas without any issues but in other situations the project won't compile and gives the exception in the compiler (When I try to pass a Lambda or a method reference to ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate).

There is a discussion in this link (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169759) where they explain why this happen. In the mean time I'm just using lambdas in my Android project when the compiler allows me.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

Comment: kindly be specific. where i need to put these two lines. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, but I had to set manually the jdk folder on program files, so I recommend to everybody specially the ones that are upgrading to java 8, to point directly in the project settings of the android studio, either using the embed option or choosing the folder

Answer (score 0):

Changing anything in build.gradle file will re-sync everything again and the error will be gone.For me i changed the minSdkVersion and it worked. Don't worry this could happen if the system crashed or Android Studio was not shut properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was not resolved by updating butterknife

from: "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0"
to:  "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"

I've tried to @BindView inside Adapter class and no success. As soon I used .findViewById(R.id.message_time), compilation had been completed successfully.