# Android Studio - what is the difference between './gradlew assembleDebug' from command line with the button 'rebuild project'?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run the command './gradlew assembleDebug' from command line, it builds successfully. However, when I click the 'rebuild project' button, I keep receiving below info.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
>   dency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33404698/5202007

Comment: Hi @Tauqie, I tried that one. The weird thing is it builds successfully by building from command line, but fails by clicking the 'rebuild project' button. I have tried to restart system but no luck.

Comment: It seems gradle issue to me. remove current gradle and use correct gradle either online or offline.