# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Error:(2055, 52) error: ';' expected Error:(2055, 59) error: <identifier> expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am new to android, my project was compiling and running properly a few moments ago but after I try to implement a navigation drawer, its giving me this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Its also complaining about a line in this generated file

> Error:(2055, 52) error: ';' expected
> Error:(2055, 59) error:  expected
> C:\Users\muoki\AndroidStudioProjects\MaterialTest\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\muoki\materialtest\R.java

which is here

```
public static final int fragment_navigation-drawer=0x7f0c0068;
```

I have tried running running using the script parameter as in explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio) question but its still giving the same error

Here is my gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.muoki.materialtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first thing you should do is remove the code you added and get back to a version that complies. Then try again. You should also supply some code because the errors are not enough to answer this problem on their own.

You should also know that the R.java file is created each time you compile the app. The error from the R.java file probably indicates that there is a problem with the way you have coded the fragment navigation drawer. Check to see if you have used any spaces in the name, the R.java error shows an underscore and a hyphen. This may indicate that there is a problem with the name.

I would also recommend looking up some youtube videos explaining how to use the LogCat output to identify errors.

You should also read through the Google documentation on navigation drawer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and compare the example code with the code you have written.

Comment: Booya! I figured it out, the problem was actually with the name with the underscore and a hyphen. The name should have been fragment_navigation_drawer and not fragment_navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0):

Its smart answer is that there is some syntax error in your Code may be in Java file or XML.

Fix them first. Error will gone.  work 100 percent for me every time
[image]

```
  Here is my Error! I found it & remove then this compile time error resolve.
```

[image]