# Android Data binding Error: HOw Can we bind ImageView If we get List of Images from model

Tags: android

I am Facing Problem to attach ImageView with model....I'm getting List of images...and after attaching with layout getting Image Setter Error... Thanks

My PostImageMOdel

```
    public class PostImageModel {
    @SerializedName("postimages_id")
    long imageId;
    @SerializedName("post_id")
    long postId;
    @SerializedName("post_image")
    String image;

    public long getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public long getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

and Here is my PostModel

```
 public class PostModel {

    @SerializedName("post_id")
    @Expose
    private String postId;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;

    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<PostImageModel> images = new ArrayList<>();
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private UserModel user;

    /**
     * @return The postId
     */
    public String getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    /**
     * @param postId The post_id
     */
    public void setPostId(String postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    /**
     * @return The userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId The user_id
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return The date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date The date
     */
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    public List<PostImageModel> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<PostImageModel> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public UserModel getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

My Layout where I am going to bind

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="house"
            type="com.gulam.dreamhome.model.PostModel" />
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/home8"
        tools:showIn="@layout/item_home_picture">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:onClick="ClickONImage"
            android:src="@{house.images[0]}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            style="@style/item_image_text_price"
            android:layout_above="@+id/city"
            android:text="@{house.price, default=price}"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            style="@style/item_image_text_city"
            android:text="@{house.city, default=City}"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:src' with parameter type com.gulam.dreamhome.model.PostImageModel on android.widget.ImageView.

Comment: post your gradle code check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio

Comment: my gradle is fine .....problem is to attach imagview with PostModel

Comment: If i remove ImageView from layout it work fine