# Error build gradle sdk version

Tags: android, xml, utf-8, sdk, apk

I got an error when build apk.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Already check on stackoverflow but didnt resolve. This is my build gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mkit.crown"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

ext {
    servicesLibVersion = '9.8.0'
    supportLibVersion = '25.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:${servicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1"
    compile "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0"
    compile "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.0"
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0"
}
```

My android sdk tool version is 26.0.0. 
It must be same on build gradle or not? i already change 25 to 26 but still got error message

Answer (score 0):

It is not the chinese character within the layout that is showing the error. The error is due to layout file name. You have to rename the layout file name to the acceptable format of android studio.

Comment: Yaa, the file name is 三樓視圖.xml, android studio detect that chinese font from folder. But if i build apk then file name error. I think i shouldnt rename all file name layouts, maybe theres another setting(?)

Comment: The layout file names must be according to the rules, hence special characters in the name will throw errors. Try renaming the layouts according to the rules, and you'll see the errors vanish.

Comment: You could easily change the file names by finding the file in the Project window and then 

Right-click >> Refactor >> Rename File

Comment: Okay, already rename it all. But, i got another errors. Error:Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character ';'. Error:Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character ''. Thats error for androidmanifest or what?

Comment: Yes that error is in the android manifest. You could see which all lines the error occurs and correct them. Make sure you changed the layout file name everywhere in the project.

Comment: hi i got error again. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: This error is in the build.gradle. Please edit your question and post your gradle file.

Comment: Since the  gradle file seems fine, I think this error has something to do with the project folder name. If there are any special characters in the project folder name, please remove them. Otherwise, try out the solutions [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio). Also please add your original question back and place the edit under it. It is not good practice to delete original question.