# Switch and Case Run Error [Android Studio]

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a questions.

I am writing the code below

```
//Switch
int day = 1;
String dayString = "";
    switch (day)
{
    case 1:
        dayString = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        dayString = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        dayString = "Wednesday";
        break;
    default:
        dayString = "Sunday";
        break;
}
```

I get this error.

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Can you provide some more info?

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a comment, so i'm putting my suggestion as an Answer.

Some suggestions:

1. Try to update your Android Studio, Gradle and Android SDK.
2. Check if your Android SDK Location is set
3. Check your Compile SDK Version, Build Tools Version, Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility (Right mouse click on your project -> Module settings -> app).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[You should read this topic,it could be usefull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio)
As far as I can see,there is nothing wrong with the switch statement