# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. error while compiling

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to compile my android project but i am getting "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'." error.
It was working fine till yesterday, but when i started today, it failed to compile.

I don't know whats the issue and also I am not much familiar with Android Studio. Can anybody please help me. Thank you.

Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.firebasedemo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
/*Firebase*/
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio please change latest buildToolsVersion.

Comment: It was "27.0.2", I changed it to check if it works, but it didn't.

Comment: Remove buildToolsVersion then sync project.

Comment: Tried, but didn't worked

Comment: Okie now changes the last solution change compileSdkVersion 26 and remove buildToolsVersion and also change all implementation then what happens.

Comment: Problem is solved by Invalidate Caches and restart. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just Invalidated Caches and restarted android studio and it worked. Don't know what was the problem, but this worked for me.

Thanks for help.

Comment: it work with **`firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'`** or with this **`firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'`**

Comment: With firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'. But i guess it will work with firebase-ui-database:3.1.0' because before compiling i changed it to 3.3.0 from 3.1.0 and thought there was issue with 3.3.0 version. So i changed it back to 3.1.0.

Comment: check here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android you should use **`firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'`**