# Compilation fails in the first run of a modified code

Tags: java, android

In *Android Studio 3.2.1*, when I change something in my code and I try to run it on my device (a phone), I get the message:

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

When I look at the Build section, I can read this:

[image: screenshot].

If I try again to run the code, without any modification, the app starts and no error is notificated.
What could be the problem?

---

**EDIT**

Here is my `build.gradle` code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: It also happens with me once in a while, but then it always work at the second attempt.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio) answer.

Comment: Copy and paste your build.gradle?

Comment: @SoonSantos, yes! It works at the second attempt, but I would like to understand why...

Comment: @Nero, I'm writing my gradle in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some files was demaged or it was an Android Studio bug: copying and pasting the code from each file into a new project solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always run your app in DEBUG mode. After that you can check the exact reason of your crash under the debug section.

Comment: What are you talking about??? The debug mode work when the app is running. My error is in the compilation phase!

Comment: Try with Invalidating Caches that might work for u then since the error is in compilation phase

Answer (score 0):

As is suggested in the image you provided, check the compiler error. click on the `Java Compiler`  in left bottom of window and then click on the error it is containing to know what went wrong.

Comment: It says that some packages does not exist, but it's not the truth.This is why it did not seem relevant to report it in the main thread...

Comment: Please at least copy paste the error, Compiler never makes mistake @Calaf

Comment: Ok. There are only 3 error, repeated a lot of times: 
`error: package name.name2.myPackage does not exist`; 
`error: cannot find symbol variable Name` (for different Names);
`error: cannot find symbol class MyClass` (for different Classes).
All these class/variable/packages are existing.

Answer (score 0):

do the instant run off and try.
File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check.

or

i think in, app>edit configuration > instant app provision your Gradle-aware is missing. so, add this by app>edit configuration > instant app provision and hit + icon and add the Gradle-aware. and also File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check .

Comment: Thanks man, but it doesn't works. And in my app there is only one activity, defined once in manifest.

Comment: i think in,

app>edit configuration > instant app provision your Gradle-aware is missing.
so,
add this by app>edit configuration > instant app provision and hit + icon and add the Gradle-aware.

and also File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check .

Comment: I've followed your instructions, but "Gradle-aware Make" was already present in instant app provision...