# React Native shows Gradle error after build failed

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I get the next error when I run "react-native run-android":

```
Error log.:

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Why this can happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio)

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure. And I'm using VS Code. I didn't find a solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You might've updated your gradle plugin, which is incompatible with the gradle files generated with the previous version, and that's likely what's causing the problem.

Only solution I know of, is to create a new React Native project and move your source code to that. If you're using multiple native libraries, it'll be a pain to link them again but your project will be built using the new gradle features and the error will go away.

Hope this helps!