# Gradle packaging error, the following problems with databinding and Androidx

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following error:

```
Task :mylibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation > > > processors are not incremental: databinding-compiler-3.4.2.jar > >>> 
(androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.2).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag 
android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties > > file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation 
incremental.FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

I have tried:

1. Running with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or --> > debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2. Getting more help at https://help.gradle.org

Getting this error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

Comment: What's the situation? Have you ever met anyone? Help see how to solve it.

Comment: There's not enough detail here for us to help you.  See for instance [Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33404552) which shows the sort of information that, when included, maximizes the chance of an answer.  See also [ask] and the [tour].  Did you rerun with `'--warning-mode all'` as suggested in the error message?  try doing so, and then [edit] you question to include build details and resulting warnings.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Did you resolve this?