# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. flutter

Tags: flutter

my project was going great till i ran `flutter clean` and then tried to run my app on android,where i got this error

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: is it the output of `flutter run` (or `flutter build`) command? if so, tried adding `-v`  switch?

Comment: flutter run command

Comment: what about `-v`?

Comment: running it with -v right now

Comment: solved it by updating my dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This issue will most likely occur when the dependencies of your app is not compatible with your development environment.

On the following SO posts, the best solution for this error is to update the dependencies as also mentioned in the comment above. To backup the references, you can refer to this SO post that exhibits the issues encountered:

- [Flutter error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177152/flutter-error-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac)
- [Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio)