# How to fix this error 'app:compiledebugjavawithjavac ' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have installed flutter and vscode also I have used android SDk comand line tool and Java Jdk8. I was trying to run my first flutter app which comes by default in flutter on my Moto G 5 Plus real android device, but this error occurred.

'''Launching lib\main.dart on Moto G 5 Plus in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)'''

**Please help me to solve this problem**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177152/flutter-error-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac)

Comment: The solution is in the error itself! Install Build Tools v 29.0.2 through SDK Manager

Answer (score -1):

Solution

1. flutter clean
2. delete android/.gradle and run
3. revert pubspec.lock and flutter pub get flutter run

Comment: Hey can you please make it more clear to me because I am new to flutter. So can you please mention steps to do it , command, and file or folder name where to do it