# How to fix "...error: cannot find symbol" build failure in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Can someone help me diagnose what is the error all about? I just can't understand what causing the error. My apologies, I just started learning Flutter this week, and assigned to a project (given only few days to study).

Based on my research, it may be due to some incorrect versions. Although I have tried changing the versions in `..app/build.gradle`. But I can't manage to solve it. I have tried these [related-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177152/flutter-error-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac) but did not work for me.

I also tried moving from one channel to another and run upgrade but same error thrown.

---

*full error message is in the snippet: (I hid it temporarily inside a snippet to shorten the stack description. I will update once the issue is solved.)*

```html
user76@user76:~/Documents/Workspace/office/fluter-office(develop)$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCachePath(options.appCachePath);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:494: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:504: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:515: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setAppCachePath(ctx.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
                ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:517: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:521: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
/home/user76/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java:767: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCachePath(newOptions.appCachePath);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

---

My **build.gradle**

```html
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.wcc.office_app_android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }

        debug {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-Dev"
        }

        stag {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".stag"
            versionNameSuffix "-Stag"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

---

My specifications

> java 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)

> Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
> Build #A1-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19,2022

> Android SDK Build-Tools 33
> Android Emulator 33.3.10
> Android SDK Platform-Tools 33.0.3
> Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) installed

> Flutter 3.3.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision ffccd96b62 (33 hours ago) • 2022-08-29 17:28:57 -0700
> Engine • revision 5e9e0e0aa8
> Tools • Dart 2.18.0 • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: Issue is with the flutter_inappwebview package. Check it's requirement of flutter and also try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: @OMiShah how to do this *Check it's requirement of flutter*?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#requirements

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do a `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`.

It seems trivial but it actually fixed a lot of my bugs.

A `flutter doctor` could give useful informations too

Comment: already ran the first 2 commands. And for the doctor all are checked.