# Dependency problem in flutter app development

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio-3.0

It is saying couldnt determine the dependency of task 'app:compiledebugjavawithjavac'

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio/33404698#33404698

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually happen when androidx not configured properly.
please check your sdk is 21 or higher and gradle.properties contain

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```