# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. - Flutter Issue

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, plugins

Trying to run the Flutter app and facing this issue. Tried each and every solution out there but didn't succeed. Below is the error what I am receiving while running the app. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Running "flutter pub get" in sample_app...
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/lj/7jcbbmp507v0bxbdfnlh56_c0000gn/T/gradle6036859919611612075.bin offset 322825 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale en)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.sample_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:<latest_version>'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Run flutter doctor and share the output of that

Comment: edited the above answer. Please check

Comment: What about your build.gradle file? Can you share it?

Comment: @Akif added both build.gradles. Please check

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404698/10659482

Comment: means, adding this: `buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"` ?

Comment: No. buildToolsVersion "29.0.2" 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223599/discussion-between-akif-and-muhammad-noman).

Comment: but my compliedVersion is 28

Comment: Ok, upgrade it to 29:      compileSdkVersion 29

Comment: Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading flutter with the command

flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I've had the very same problem. It just started without any reason or change in code. Solved it by accident when I upgraded flutter and then got back to the previous flutter version:

```
flutter upgrade    
flutter downgrade vX.X.X
```