# How to fix this build error for capacitor in android studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

Im trying to compile my first ionic app with capacitor for android. Gradle successfuly builds it but when I try to run it on android studio i get this error:

```
 Failed to query the value of task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
```

> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\jsprojects\ajoopay2\node_modules@capacitor\android\capacitor\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@482d6451) before task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

I have no idea what to do and ive spent hours trying to correct this please help me

Comment: check this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio"

Comment: Lol. Ive been to that page like 50 times, no help

Comment: any luck fixing this issue? @NobleEugene

Comment: Try downgrading gradle version @madroid

Answer (score 8):

**sometimes** this happens when yours

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x-x-x.zip

incompatible with yours project build.gradle

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:y.y.y'

Good luck resolving this, android studio will not give you any clue about it smilyface

Answer (score -4):

I found a fix. I just had to downgrade my version of gradle from 7 to 5.
Next time im installing android studio ill make sure to use the gradle version suggested