# Flutter error: Execution failed for task ':location_permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, dart

Tried to run my flutter app on a physical device, and the following error keeps showing:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 3a in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_api_availability-2.0.4/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/googleapiavailability/GoogleApiAvailabilityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.3.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.2.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.2.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/streamhandler/TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
            || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION));
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
            || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION));
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:308: error: cannot find symbol
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:309: error: cannot find symbol
        names.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:330: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && hasPermissionInManifest(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, context)) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:330: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && hasPermissionInManifest(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, context)) {
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:331: error: cannot find symbol
      permissionNames.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
/Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:372: error: cannot find symbol
      return locationManager.isLocationEnabled();
                            ^
  symbol:   method isLocationEnabled()
  location: variable locationManager of type LocationManager
Note: /Users/jasonlloyd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-3.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/location_permissions/LocationPermissionsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location_permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried following the advice here: [Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio) but doesn't work still. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I simply needed to update one of my dependencies in pubspec.yaml to the latest version, specifically changing location pacakage to `location: ^4.3.0`. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow Background location in Manifest?

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- Required only when requesting background location access on
       Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did already do that, and it didn't work still. But upgrading to the latest version of the location package worked! Thanks for your help though really appreciate it