# react-native : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, build

When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease` on my project, I get an build error of gradle.
Someone can help me?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de rÚpertoire ou de volume est incorrecte

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.     

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warning
```

Comment: Lots of related info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio, to start I would check that the JAVA_HOME environment variable has been set so javac will be available.  Can you post the output of echo $JAVA_HOME. I would also suggest you add the app.build.gradle file to your question