# Android Studio error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to compile an app in Android Studio and I'm constantly getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

There's a similar question here: [Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio)

I tried almost all of the answers in the above Question and nothing seems to work!

This is my `build.gradle` (Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"
    def dagger_version = "2.27"
    def work_version = "2.4.0"

    //Navigation Jetpack
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    //Lifecycle Jetpack
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    //ROOM DB
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    //GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

    //RXJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'


    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'

    //Dagger 2
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    // Dagger Android
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"

    // Reactive Streams (convert Observable to LiveData)
    def reactivestreams_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$reactivestreams_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Google maps
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    //Shimmer animation
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    //local DB debug
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'

    //floating button
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

    //lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    //swipe to delete
    implementation 'it.xabaras.android:recyclerview-swipedecorator:1.2.1'

    //work manager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0-alpha01'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'


    //ml vision api
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'


    //maps location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    //jackson parser
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //chart
    implementation 'com.mdgiitr.suyash:graphkit:0.9.0'

}
```

Could someone please point me in a right direction and advice on this issue?

**EDIT:**

I'm running the latest Android Studio on a Mac machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve this issue by adding this to my build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
    }
}
```

I didn't upgrade the gradle either!

Comment: It would be appreciated if you give an explanation too. It would help beginners.

Answer (score 14):

This exception occurs also if **Jetpack Room < 2.4.0-alpha03** is used on Apple's M1 chip.

This can be fixed by adding the right dependency to the gradle file

```
def room_version = "2.4.0-alpha03" //Needs to be this version to build on apple M1 chips

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.4.0-alpha03).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on M1 Pro Macbook and fixed by changing

```
 //local storage
 //implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
    def room_version = "2.4.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate answer. I voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Official Android site](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError), this error is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable. The problem is in your code. See any unnecessary static idenitfier, and post your code in a repo :)

Comment: unfortunately this is not my code! its someone else's that Im working on and its been written very badly as well! its also a huge code! in Xcode usually you can find out the offending code and resolve the issue but Android studio has a long way to catch up.

Comment: That's a problem! Is the java/kotlin code clean? I mean check for any red lines and post the error.

Comment: there isn't java/kotlin !

Comment: Then why are you compiling through Javac? And you've mentioned the java tag with your question!

Comment: I'm literally doing Build >> Build Bundles/Apks >> Build APK in android studio! am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Firstly, in which language is your code written in?

Comment: Java I believe...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237370/discussion-between-justincoding-and-rooz-far).

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: please view my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while fixing othr crash.
There was change in the order of methods ( lines ) in MyApplications onCreate, I needed to make sure super.oncreate is called before,

instance = this
be placed before where
the  instance was later used in the code.
Actually in the stackTrace it showed that the crash was actually due to a null pointer exception.

Kindly check the stacktrace for other exceptions.