# There are no issues with iOS, but when building for the Android emulator, an error occurs

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to build my Flutter app in debug mode for the Android emulator, but I'm encountering an error. (I have included the error message below.) However, I have no issues building it in debug mode for the iOS emulator.

How can I resolve this problem?

Here is the error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not create task ':app:generateDebugLintModel'.
      > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I will provide the error message below, which occurred when executing 'flutter run --verbose' command. (Since it is a long text, I will only include the top part.)

```
'/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_android-3.7.1/android/build.gradle'.
[        ] All projects evaluated.
[        ] Task name matched 'assembleDebug'
[        ] Selected primary task 'assembleDebug' from project :
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[        ] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
[        ]    > Could not create task ':app:generateDebugLintModel'.
[        ]       > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the
dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

```dart
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.3, on macOS 13.3.1  darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.10.3 on channel stable at /Users/user/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f92f44110e (4 days ago), 2023-06-01 18:17:33 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/user/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

I have tried executing commands such as 'flutter clean' and 'flutter pub cache repair,' but it did not resolve the issue. I also ran 'flutter pub outdated' and tried updating to the recommended versions as a temporary solution, but it did not make a difference.

Additional note:
I have installed Java.

% brew install openjdk
% sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
% echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
% export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include"

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but when I ran ./android/gradlew clean, I encountered the following error.

`The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java. `

Comment: Based on your comment it might be that you didn't install the correct java? or that flutter is not connected to it. Did you also open the project in android studio? Does the android emulator it self work?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I usually develop using VSCode instead of Android Studio, so I am not familiar with that aspect. However, when I open the Flutter project in Android Studio, I encounter an error related to 'Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: In my case, when I run flutter doctor -v, there don't seem to be any issues, so I believe there are no problems related to Java. However, do I need to configure something additional?

Comment: I don't know if android requires more setup. That should be answered on the setup documentation

Comment: What do you mean by 'setup document'?

Comment: You can check if you have done everything for the android set up: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Comment: "Since I can debug on Android without any issues in another project, I don't think it's a matter of incomplete configuration."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions.
As a solution to the issue, I was able to run it without any problems by removing the "background_fetch" package

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to the issue, I was able to run it without any problems by removing the "background_fetch" package