# Permission handler in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

Currently, I can successfully compile and build an APK for my Flutter application without encountering any issues. However, as soon as I include the 'permission_handler' package, I am unable to do so. I have tried using multiple versions of the 'permission_handler' package, but the problem persists. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
error: warnings found and -error specified
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task

```
':permission_handler_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404698/7819821 ?

Comment: Yes, and the same error

Comment: And this one https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/910 as well?

Comment: I  got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Java version on my computer from 20 to 11 and it works.

Comment: I've got the same problem with jdk21. Moving to jdk17 helped.

Answer (score 0):

try adding permission on androidmanifest.xml

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work